# How can I copy only changed files from one S3 Bucket to another one with python using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to copy files from one S3 Bucket to another S3 Bucket every x minutes. But of course I only want to update the files if they have changed how can I achieve that with python using boto3?

Comment: what have you tried? how do you know what files have changed (is your bucket versioned etc).

Comment: The easiesst thing to do IMO is to add a lambda that triggers on file change and copies the files (you trigger once on each file whenever they change, instead of having to poll the bucket evvery x minutes) but that might be too complicated

Comment: So far i've just been copying the files no matter if they changed, can i possibly use the ETAG? My Buckets are versioned yes.

Comment: I guess you can check the date modified on bucket1, and date created on bucket 2 and then copy them if a) they dont exist on bucket 2 (new file) b) they dont match within x minutes + margin of error, but it looks a bit dirty

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Amazon S3 replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html), which can automatically copy objects from one bucket to another.

You can select which objects to copy by specifying a path or a tag.

It's all automatic.